# Get closest page ID from URL

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls, parse

Lets say on my WordPress website I navigate to:

> www.example.com/media-centre/news/17/an-example-news-post

In this case I am looking at a post in a CPT called `News`.

What I want to do is get the page ID thats closest to that URL. I know the closest page ID can be found at:

> www.example.com/media-centre/news/

So how do I loop back over my URL to find the closest page and then how do I get the ID of that page?

Comment: By closest do you mean a news CPT with post ID closest to '17'?

Comment: No. I'm after a `Page ID` here nothing to do with posts. The closest page in my example is `/media-centre/news/`, in this example I would be after the `Page ID` of `news`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got there myself with the aid from Stephen Harris and some PHP help over at SO.

```
$page = get_closest_page();

// echo $page->ID;

function get_closest_page( $url = false )
{
    global $wp;

    if( ! $url )
        $url = $wp->request;

    $page = get_page_by_path( $url );

    if( $page )
        return $page;

    $url = dirname( $url );

    return get_closest_page( $url );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the current url from `$url = add_query_arg()`.

Then assuming, the structure: `www.example.com/page/subpage/news/ID/post` you can use `preg_match` to extract `/page/subpage/news`. Then it would be simple matter of using [`get_page_by_path();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path).

If that fails you can then check `/page/subpage/` and finally `/page`.